# jQuery Hover Fade Button with an Active State

Tags: jquery

I do not want to double post a question; I was trying to post an add-on to my first question that I was looking for additional help. How does one go about this?

Here is the original question. [jQuery Hover Fade Button with an Active State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396932)

Was hoping to see if there is a solution to the glitch I found.

The problem I am now looking for help with is all other buttons still have the hover effect, but a button that was once active no longer does.

```
<ul class="buttons">
    <li><a class="button" href="#">button 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="button" href="#">button 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="button" href="#">button 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Best way to explain this. If button 2 is clicked – it is now active. Buttons 1 and 3 will still hover. If you click on button 1 – it is now active and button 2 will no longer hover while button 3 will. Eventually when you go through the series of all buttons the animation hover is no longer.

Comment: Please post your jQuery code to keep it all together.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might do what you need... I wasn't sure if you wanted to fade out the active button while you were still hovered over it, but that's what I did.

```
<ul class="buttons">
    <li><a class="button" href="#">button 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="button" href="#">button 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="button" href="#">button 3</a></li>
</ul>
<script>
$('a.button').each(function () {
 var text = $(this).text();

 $(this).append('<span class="hover">'+text+'</span>').find('.hover').css('opacity', 0);

 $(this)
  .hover(function () {
   $(this).find('.hover').stop().fadeTo(500, 1);
  }, function () {
   $(this).find('.hover').stop().fadeTo(500, 0);
  })
  .click (function () {
   $('a.button > span').removeClass('active').addClass('hover');
   $(this).find('span').addClass('active').removeClass('hover').stop().fadeTo(500, 0);
  });
});
</script>
```

I also thought about using the toggleClass function instead...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help that is a different effect the classes worked - except the text didn't get carried over and got dropped.

Comment: Please write this as a comment.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean... the text didn't get carried over and got dropped? Are you saying you want the <span> to remain if the item is selected?